# Calling entityManager.flush - effects of calling it twice, once or not at all

Tags: java, spring, jpa, entitymanager

Do I have to call the `entityManager.flush()` or is data written automatically on exit when the method has a @Transactional annotation?

Also, if I call it twice do I always get a no transaction exception?

```
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "CONFIGURATION", type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
    private EntityManager entityManager;

@Transactional
    public boolean generate() {
        doStuffToDatabase();
        //entitymanager.flush();
        //entitymanager.flush(); //If I call it twice do I always get a no transaction exception?
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

When you change entities inside a transaction, you aren't actually changing the database, but rather the in-memory model of the rows. When your transaction is commited, the changes to the in-memory model will be flushed to the database, meaning that the necessary SQL-queries to bring the state of the database to the state of the model will be executed.

When invoking entityManager.flush manually, all you are doing is syncing these changes before the transaction is complete. This has a few implications:

- If your transaction ends up being cancelled (an exception occurs after the invocation of flush), Hibernate/JPA will have to perform a database rollback, which will be a performance cost
- If the state of your model ends up with violating a constraint in the database, a manual flush will force this error at an earlier stage. This will typically interrupt the execution of your Java when you call flush, rather than at transaction commit time.

In general, there should be no need to do manual flushing. The only real gain I can see is my second point here, where it is necessary to stop execution at once, if there is a constraint violation. But in my mind, this is a code smell, and should be easily avoided by knowing what changes you can and can't do, as well as a correct setup of transactions.

Calling flush a second time, without any changes to the model in between, will not have any effect, as all changes are already made to the database.

Answer (score 2):

When the `@Transactional` method complete successfully , it will commit the transaction . Before committing the transaction , it will automatically call `flush()` behind the scene if you do not call it explicitly.

`flush()` will immediately cause JPA to issue SQL to insert or update the related database records if there are any pending changes in the persistence context. Calling flush again immediately after the first flush is meaningless as all the pending changes in the persistence context is already updated to database in the first flush.

We normally manually call `flush()` when we need to update a large amount of records to prevent the server from running out of the memory . The idea is that after making changes for certain batch of records , we flush and clear the persistence context and then go on to process other batches.